# concept confusion, advices on solving these 2 code

Tags: methods

In O() notation, write the complexity of the following code:

```
For i = 1 to x                               functi
    call funct(i)                          if (x <= 0)
                                                       return some value
                                                 else




In O() notation, write the complexity of the following code:

For x = 1 to N
```

I'm really lost at solving these 2 big O notation complexity problem, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both appear to me to be O(N).

The first one subtracts by 1 when it calls itself, this means if given N, then it runs N times.

The second one divides the N by 2, but Big-O is determined by worst case scenario, which means that we must assume N is getting significantly larger. When you take that into account, dividing by 2 does not have much of a difference. That means while it originally is O(N/2) it can be reduced to O(N)